# Qt: How to remove the default main toolbar from the mainwindow?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qtgui

I am new to Qt, and I can't figure out why there is a draggable object in my main window. It starts at the top of the screen in its exapanded form.

[image]

And then I can drag it and it shrinks into a square.

[image]

Comment: That is your toolbar that is created automatically when you create a new Qt GUI project.

Comment: How do I remove this default toolbar and what is the purpose of it?

Comment: You can remove it by opening the `mainwindow.ui` file in the designer. In the object inspector list (located in the top right corner) you will see an object named `mainToolBar`. You can right click it and select `Remove toolbar`. You can read the [docs about `QToolBar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#details) to learn more about it. It's basically a box that contains different controls, like buttons and menus.

Comment: There are three objects, the main tool bar, the status bar, and the menu bar. Removing any of them doesn't seem to change the result after building.

Comment: Did you save the changes you made to the `mainwindow.ui`? Try running `qmake` and rebuilding:`Build` => `Run qmake` and `Build` => `Rebuild Project`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the main toolbar from either QtDesigner as can be seen below or from the code manually:

[image]

Then, you will need to rerun qmake for the changes to take effect as the `ui_mainwindow.h` header file needs to be regenerated from the updated `mainwindow.ui` description file.

[image]