# How do I get rid of this anonymous draggable bar in qtcreator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I wrote a program in qt creator, but it includes this anonymous draggable toolbar that I would like to get rid of. It does not show up in design mode. If I right click on it, it gives me a menu with a checkbox, which I can select to get rid of it while the program is running. What is this bar? How do I get rid of it? If I knew what it was, I could just programmatically tell it to hide when the program loads.

Here are some screenshots demonstrating this weird problem. In the first screenshot, the mouse is pointed at the bar. The second one demonstrates the right-click context menu. The third one shows the program without the bar. The box can also be dragged out of the program's window entirely. I can also upload a picture of that, if necessary.

(mouse pointing at bar)
[image: screen with box]

(bar has a right-click menu!)
[image: right-click menu]

(bar is gone)
[image: no more box]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: How to remove the default main toolbar from the mainwindow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314748/qt-how-to-remove-the-default-main-toolbar-from-the-mainwindow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, make sure you haven't added the toolbar yourself in code (the Designer form is nothing magical, it just generates normal Qt code to `ui_XXXX.h`, which you should totally study, so you understand what is really happening "under the hood").

Second, perhaps that is the main menu bar, not the main tool bar.

Then, on to remove the nasty bar. On the upper right corner of Design view, you have a tree of all items in your UI. Find the QToolBar there. It is probably called `mainToolBar`. Right click it and remove it there. Or, if you actually have menu bar, then find QMenuBar, probably called `menuBar`, and remove it instead. Remember to make version control commit (or other backup) before doing this, so you can easily revert changes.

---

If this fails for whatever reason, and you just want to get it to work, you can always find and delete (be careful about the dangling pointers left behind, set them to `nullptr` if possible):

```
ui->setupUi(this);
// a hack: we want to get rid of the toolbar and the menubar,
// but can't remove it from the .ui, so we delete them like this.
delete findChild<QToolBar *>(); // NULL return value is ok for delete
delete findChild<QMenuBar *>(); // NULL return value is ok for delete
```

Doc links for [`findChild`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) and alternative [`findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren).

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is probably the `mainToolBar` `QToolBar` object you get with every QDesigner-created QMainWindow `.ui` file.
If you want to get rid of it, locate it in your `.ui` file and just delete it.

But better think twice: you might later decide you **want** a QToolBar object and (at least AFAIK) there is no way to recreate it in QDesigner...

Comment: My `mainwindow.ui` file does have any mainToolBar, or even any 'bar' or 'Bar' under search. `mainwindow.ui` is the only ui file that I see in qtcreator.

Comment: Strange. What QtCreator version are you on? I get this QToolBar object when creating a new project (and apparently it is there for you as well?). What are the three last objects in the QDesigner plugin Object view (usually the top right view in the designer window)?

Comment: My qtcreator is version 3.5.1. In the Object view, the only object is MainWindow. MainWindow has one child, centralWidget, and its only child is the program's tabWidget.

Comment: A word of warning: you generally should not edit `.ui` file by hand, as it is very easy to break it for Designer (meaning, it won't work correctly in Designer after that). It's not meant to be edited by hand (as demonstrated by Qt Creator refusing to do it when you look at it as text).

Answer (score 0):

you must use this code in your constructor.
**ui->mainToolBar->toggleViewAction()->setVisible(false);**

mainToolBar is my toolbar name.